# Using GitVersion, What is the difference between NuGetVersionV2 & NuGetVersion

Tags: nuget, gitversion

Using GitVersion, What is the difference between variables NuGetVersionV2 & NuGetVersion?  The examples found [here](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/variables/) show them as the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the minute, they are exactly the same.

As you can see here:

https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/blob/05161c36debf88b4278b7d57553ccae4c62d1174/src/GitVersionCore/SemanticVersionFormatValues.cs#L120

If I recall correctly, I think the idea was that there would always be a NuGetVersion, which would always give you a Semantic Version Number that works with the latest version of NuGet, but if you wanted to take a dependency on a Semantic Version number that would work with a specific NuGet Version, you have that option too.

Comment: So I should use NuGetVersion instead of NuGetVersionV2 to use the latest NuGet compatible version number?

Comment: What version of NuGet are you currently using to do the packaging?

Comment: The latest, Nuget v3

Comment: In which case, I would suggest that you use NuGetVersion.